# EXCEL VBA user defined function - else without if

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, user-defined-functions

The attached code is run on VBA, but I do not understand why there is an error says else without if or if without end if. I am pretty sure that I have matched every end if with if statement.

Sub teee() is just for testing the decimalize function. It would be greatly check the code and tell me what is wrong with my code... I am almost close to complete a project if I can troubleshoot this function.

```
Sub teee()

sss = "-1-21+"

MsgBox (decimalize(sss))


End Sub
```

---

```
Function decimalize(s As Variant) As Long

Dim checkers As Variant
Dim ab As Long
Dim leftnum As Long
Dim rightnum As Long
Dim poneg As Integer


checkers = s
ab = 0
leftnum = 0
rigntnum = 0
poneg = 0

'Positive payup or negative payup

If Left(checkers, 1) = "-" Then
poneg = 1
lencheckers = Len(checkers)
checkers = Mid(checkers, 2, lencheckers - 1)

Else: poneg = 0
End If


startp = InStr(checkers, "-")


If startp = 2 Then leftnum = Left(checkers, 1)
ElseIf startp = 3 Then leftnum = Left(checkers, 2)
ElseIf startp = 4 Then leftnum = Left(checkers, 3)
End If



rightnum = Mid(checkers, startp + 1, 2)


If InStr(checkers, "+") > 0 Then
ab = 0.5
ElseIf InStr(checkers, "1/4") > 0 Then
ab = 0.25
ElseIf InStr(checkers, "1/8") > 0 Then
ab = 0.125
End If

rightnum = rightnum + ab


If poneg = 0 Then
decimalize = rightnum + leftnum * 32
ElseIf poneg = 1 Then
decimalize = (rightnum + leftnum * 32) * -1
End If


End Function
```

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Change it like this:

```
If startp = 2 Then
    leftnum = Left(checkers, 1)
ElseIf startp = 3 Then leftnum = Left(checkers, 2)
ElseIf startp = 4 Then leftnum = Left(checkers, 3)
End If
```

Info: When you write the result after the "then" on the same line, should not write end if. Thus, VBA does not understand where the next ElseIf is coming from.

Pretty much you are allowed to use the following two examples:

```
'Example 1 (no end if here)
if startp = 2 then leftnum = Left(checkers,1)

'Example 2 (you need end if here)
if startp = 2 then
    leftnum = Left(checkers,1)
end if
```

Comment: Much appreciated, Vityata, your solution has worked perfectly!

Comment: Good to know, +1 karma for today :) If you want, you may select the answer by clicking the left green check like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

@Vityata showed one way to eliminate that particular bug. Another way is to avoid `If` altogether and use a `Select Case`. The resulting code is somewhat more readable:

```
Select Case startp
    Case 2: leftnum = Left(checkers, 1)
    Case 3: leftnum = Left(checkers, 2)
    Case 4: leftnum = Left(checkers, 3)
End Select
```

Also, You have an arbitrary pattern of declaring some variables but not others, and you have at least one variable typo: `rigntnum = 0` should almost certainly be `rightnum = 0`. You really need to use `Option Explicit`at the top of all of your modules (also, enable `Require Variable Declaration` in the VBA editor options). That will help you write code that isn't prone to random bugs.

Comment: Thank you for great advice John, Will do for the next time. Using several IF statements at the same time always makes me complicated.